# Redraw [sample]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

The [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sample) tag is for a...

> Small part of or a selection from something (code , logs , data and etc.), intended to show the structure, style, or nature of the whole.

In practice, [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sample) is mostly used

- in a way that is synonymous with [random-sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/random-sample) or
- (rarely) [to refer to audio samples](https://stackoverflow.com/?tags=audio%20sample&mode=all).

Because people like to type in "sample" when referring to random sampling, I think we should [make "sample" a synonym of "random-sample"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/random-sample/synonyms). To deal with the 50 "audio sample" questions, we could manually apply a new tag [audio-sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-sample) or just get rid of tagging to cover that topic (if "audio samples" aren't central enough to programming to deserve their own tag). Thoughts?

Comment: Mm.. why should be a tag for data sources? Is like [parsing] or [scrapping]