# Should we withdraw [redraw]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

Reading [Redraw [sample]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299731) made me think, do we have a [redraw] tag?

Yes, [redraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redraw) has 273 questions, with 43 asked this year. When I look into it the questions are in almost every language which deals with drawing(js,java,c#,python...).

Should we synonymize it with [draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/draw)?
Or should we just burn it?

([redraw] isn't always accompanied by [draw] though...)

Comment: Burn! BURN IT ALL!!!! It's a meta-tag at best.